# Can't boot Android x86 after installing from iso

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, android-x86

I've installed Android x86 7.1 on a VMware virtual machine with IDE virtual disk. After I restart the vm, it boots from the iso file, not from the virtual disk on which I've installed the OS.

Answer (score 1):

did you check the boot sequence ? probably set to boot first from the "cdrom" aka your ISO. Or just unmount the ISO in VMware

Comment: When I remove the cdrom, it says no os installed.

Comment: then you didn't install it :) you just booted from the iso-file; you have to actually install it to the harddisk (see other topics on how to do)